# yii export tables into excel sheet in CSV Format

Tags: yii

Hello Sir I want to ask how to export my few tables data in excel sheet format in list manner

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "list manner" but you could create a link that uses [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) and use the template attributes to only use your view `'template'=>'{items}',` and [turn off paging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#enablePagination-detail). Then [set the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382604/what-to-set-as-mimetype-for-csv-files-to-open-in-spreadsheet-applications) of your file with php for the appropriate file type, etc. If you need something more sophisticated than CSV, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel/3931142#3931142).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-export or something like this:

```
public function actionDownloadExcel() {
    $data = <here some query>;
    $data = unserialize( $data);
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=windows-1251' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv' );
    $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
    fwrite( $output, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" );
    fputcsv( $output, [ 'field1', 'field2', 'field3' ], ';' );
    foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
        fputcsv( $output, $value, ';' );
    }
}
```

in you Controller. More documentation at http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others and provide the link for reference.