# Proper syntax for optional header parameter for text/csv mimetype?

Tags: csv, mime-types, rfc4180

According to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

> ...the presence or absence of the header line
> should be indicated via the optional "header" parameter of this
> MIME type...

So, does that mean the correct string is:

```
text/csv; header
```

Or perhaps:

```
text/csv; header=true
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The "header" parameter indicates the presence or absence of the header line.  Valid values are "present" or "absent".

So if you use that parameter, the full MIME type would be `text/csv; header=present` or `text/csv; header=absent`.