# Filepicker does not accept mimetype 'text/csv' on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io

I am using filepicker and set the mimetype for the upload on 'text/csv'. It works pretty well on Mac chrome, but on windows it does not. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Ace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the alternative mimetypes as well:

```
text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel
```

Source: http://filext.com/file-extension/CSV