# Invoking out of browser app from in-browser app in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

We need to have the functionality of users running excel reports from a silverlight application. The application will show data from the server and upon clicking a button users should see an excel report from the data in their client machines. We can't make the original application out of browser so I am looking for options.

I am thinking of creating an out of browser application which can invoke excel in the client machine. Our original application just have to download and install the out of browser application with user permissions. Also I need to pass the data for the excel report from the in-browser application to the OOB applications.

Is it possible? If it is, is there any help available how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is to popup another browser window from your in-browser Silverlight application and then offer excel file download to the client. By default this dialog offers Open option as well and that could solve your problem. That's how I solved excel report download from SSRS in my Silverlight application.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to let users [download data as CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382604/what-to-set-as-mimetype-for-csv-files-to-open-in-spreadsheet-applications) from the browser, which will open in Excel for most users.

You can also copy [delimited text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx) to the user's clipboard using [Clipboard.SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043(v=vs.95).aspx) which the user can then paste into a running instance of Excel.

Another option would be to use a server-side service to [generate an Excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) and have the Silverlight application show a hyperlink to the document.